# Mac OSX, Automator: Error with simple shell script

Tags: macos, automator

I want the mysql server to start on every startup of my mac. Usually I do this via the command line with `mysql.server start`.
Now I wanted to automate the process and for the first time I worked with Automator. So I added a "shell script", configured of "/bin/bash" and pasted the command. When I start it I'm getting a popup with an error. It's german so I cannot translate it 1:1. It says something like "An error occured during the action "Execute Shell-Script".

Comment: To run a shell command once at startup a launchd agent with `RunAtLoad - true` might be the better solution

Comment: Try looking at the manpages for `launchd` and `launchctl`.